# Div vertical-align in a gwt-page

Tags: css, gwt

I am trying to set a div element on the right top of a web-page which contains a span, a label and a button. I want to bring all the elements in alignment regarding the vertical high (preferably at the middle of the div element). However vertical-align: middle does not work as the elements are cling to the top of the div. They are probably influenced by an external div or Panel (since I use gwt). Should I interfere in the default attributes of the gwt widgets? What other solution can you suggest? 
The code:

```
<div class="{style.topRightDisplay}">
                <span style="float:left;">Eingeloggt als: </span>
                <g:HTML ui:field="loginHTML" addStyleNames="{style.loginHTML}"></g:HTML>
                <g:Button ui:field="logoutButton" addStyleNames="{style.button}">Logout</g:Button>
            </div>


.button {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }   

.loginHTML {
        float: left;
    }

    .topRightDisplay {
        float: right;
        height: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand the purpose of vertical-align. See the [explanation of vertical-align on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/vertical-align)

You need to apply vertical-align to the child elements, not the parent.
Without knowing what your markup looks like, I suggest this:

```
.topRightDisplay input,
.topRightDisplay button, 
.topRightDisplay span{
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

You should also remove the floats. Floats make an item render as a block-level element, which means vertical-align won't work.

Instead you can use display: inline-block. You may need to change the order of the elements in hmtl to get the result you want.

Comment: Without the float they come one below each other, not in an horizontal line as desired.